# HTML input file multiple sort by user select order

Tags: javascript, html

If a user selects multiple files, it needs to be ordered by user selection priority (like facebook). FileList needs to depend on user order.

Here is a sample code:

```js
  function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

    // files is a FileList of File objects. List some properties.
    var output = [];
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
      output.push('<li><strong>', escape(f.name), '</strong> (', f.type || 'n/a', ') - ',
                  f.size, ' bytes, last modified: ',
                  f.lastModifiedDate ? f.lastModifiedDate.toLocaleDateString() : 'n/a',
                  '</li>');
    }
    document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = '<ul>' + output.join('') + '</ul>';
  }

  document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

```html
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
<output id="list"></output>
```

It always changes order when you select the second file which is upper position to the first .
Please check the images

[image]
I selected the first image , which name is 89......*

[image]
When I selected the second image above from first image , the name order changed . And also FileList changed. Please help me to get the order as user selected . Thanks.

(I also tried with many images randomly selected from a folder but final result is ordered automatically)

Answer (score 1):

You are using an operating system supplied file chooser and that's just how it works in Windows. You cannot change its behaviour, and it may be different on other operating systems (Linux, MacOS). If the order is essential for your purposes then you could implement your own custom control, but then you lose the benefit of reusing the convenient built-in function that users are familiar with.

An alternative is to allow your user to customize the order after they click `Open` and you have processed the input. This would let them use the familiar interface but for selection, but the flexibility of controlling the order. If you do this, then I'd recommend sorting them consistently by filename first so that the operation is consistent between operating systems.

Comment: Thank you. It seems to be not easy way for me . :)