# How to print the multiple input order "File name" in html and JS

Tags: javascript, html

I have five files scan.pdf, "1_PVC", "2_Graham", 3_TAC, "4_TEC", I want the console.log can print retrieve the exact same string ("scan" "1_PVC" "2_Graham" 3_TAC "4_TEC") inside the filename. No matter how I get, it will eventually get from Alphabetical order "1_PVC" ... This is what I've done so far.

```
<input type="file" name="filess[]" id="file" accept=".pdf" multiple="multiple"  />
var filess = event.target.files;
console.log(filess);

var count = files.length;

for (var k=0; k<file.files.length; ++k){
    console.log(files[i].name + "\n");
}
```

[image]

Any method I can print the "File name:" based on user selection.

Comment: What broswer are you using? I have tried with my own files in firefox. For me the disorder happens when selecting them. If I put them in the order I want in the dialogue box, by this I mean selecting them, and then changing the order they appear in the text box of the dialogue box, then the console shows them in that order.

Comment: also your code references `filess`, `files`, and `file.files`. I'm not sure which is correct, but they can't all be.

Comment: Like MattEllen said, same with me on W11 Edge.

Comment: I don't think it can be done due to it is OS specific. The order in Windows is following the order in the file explorer (which in your picture is sorted by Name). If you click the "Date Modified" column to sort it by date, then the print order will also follow. See also this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58694968/html-input-file-multiple-sort-by-user-select-order

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8' />
<script>
function logFiles(){
    var list=document.getElementById('filesElement').files;
    var listlen=list.length;
    for (var filenum=0;filenum<listlen;filenum++){
        console.log(list[filenum].name);
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type='file' id='filesElement' multiple='multiple' onchange='logFiles();' />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the FilePicker api (as it preserves order from selection):

```
    const fileHandles = await window.showOpenFilePicker({multiple: true});
    console.log(fileHandles.map(fh => fh.name));
```

You can also read and write local files using the FileSystem API. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystem
The FilePicker only works in Edge and Chrome atm though: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/showOpenFilePicker